# Column html css

Tags: php, html, css

I need to split a text in *two columns*, but my need is to **print**. I need to have the first text be filled with text and then let the text skip to the second column. The paper size is **A4**.

My solution is not the following:

```
.two-column {
   height: 29 cm;
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-width: 9.5cm;
   -webkit-column-width: 9.5cm;
   -moz-column-gap: 10px;
   -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Using this code it divides the text evenly, but I want fill the first column with text and then skip to the the second column.

Solutions in `Php`, `Javascript` and other languages are fine.

Comment: Have you tried adding `min-height` as well?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in JSFiddle and it works fine.

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/w9sotbb7/

The CSS code:

```
.columns {
    height: 297mm;
    width: 210mm;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width: 95mm;
    -webkit-column-width: 95mm;
    -moz-column-gap: 5mm;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5mm;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

I added `text-align: justify` for making the text looking more beautiful.
Using a metric unit for the gap is better than using px. Actually it is better to use metric units for all attributes in CSS if you're creating a print layout.

The best would be to enclose the CSS code for the print layout in a media query:

```
@media print {
  /* CSS selectors and values */
}
```

Thus you can create a different look and feel for printing and for the screen. Think also on the margins when printing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I do not know if I explained well, but the answer did not solve my problem.

Example: to complete the first column I need a text with 30 lines. when start the text line 31 the text need to go for second column.

These CSS code divite for the same columns. then do not solve my problem.

Comment: This is for printing, isn't it? Than you can set another height (other than 210mm). It must not fill out the whole page. Let's say `height: 150mm`. If you want exactly 30 lines in a column define `line-height: 5mm`. Now you can have up to 30 rows in a column. Take care that the font size is less than 5 mm. And for the height, you also have to take care for the margins, so maybe height of 150mm with top and bottom margins of 30mm would fit pretty well.

Comment: Sorry, I confused little bitt the height and the width values when mentioning the margins.

Comment: ok, perfect
I put to work in chrome, but when I print it appears in a column.
Already in firefox it did not work as it should, for it is dividing evenly.
I shared the screen print:

Comment: you don't mess with the mark I used 30 lines with example. I do not know how many rows are for real.

Comment: .columns {
    height: 297mm;
    width: 210mm;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width: 95mm;
    -webkit-column-width: 95mm;
    -moz-column-gap: 5mm;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5mm;
    text-align: justify;
}

@media print {
.columns {
    height: 297mm;
    width: 210mm;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width: 95mm;
    -webkit-column-width: 95mm;
    -moz-column-gap: 5mm;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5mm;
    text-align: justify;
}
}